# Jquery plugin stops working correctly after window.resize, but works well after full page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, window-resize

I'm implementing a jquery carousel into my page. Because I have used percentage units rather than fixed units, I need to redraw the carousel after window resize.

My problem is that the carousel stops to work correctly and its function call does not behave normally and renders the carousel oddly after resizing using the following code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
                FnUpdateCarousel();                                                                                         
            }); // end ready    

            var lightbox_resize = false;
            $(window).resize(function() {
                if (lightbox_resize)
                    clearTimeout(lightbox_resize);
                lightbox_resize = setTimeout(function() {
                    FnUpdateCarousel(); 
                }, 100);
            });                                         

            function FnUpdateCarousel() {
                    var widthof = 
                    Math.round(parseInt(jQuery('#services-example-1').css('width'))-(45));
                    jQuery('#services-example-1').services(
                        {
                            width:widthof,
                            height:290,
                            slideAmount:6,
                            slideSpacing:30,
                            touchenabled:"on",
                            mouseWheel:"on",
                            hoverAlpha:"off",
                            slideshow:3000,
                            hovereffect:"off"
                        });
                };
```

Please guide me on how can I make it behave normally.

Comment: I suspect that you're not supposed to reinitialize the entire carousel over and over again.  If you can be more specific about what jQuery plug-in you are using, folks might have a better idea how to help.  I would suggest checking the documentation for how to resize a carousel that is already running.

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00, FYI: http://www.themepunch.com/codecanyon/showbiz/

Comment: That is the carousel I'm working to integrate.

Comment: It doesn't look like their documentation is public so we can't help.  I think you need to study the doc and find out how they suggest you resize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I reached:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var initialContent = jQuery('#services-example-1').html();
            jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
                FnUpdateCarousel();                                                                                         
            }); // end ready    

            var lightbox_resize = false;
            $(window).resize(function() {
                if (lightbox_resize)
                    clearTimeout(lightbox_resize);
                lightbox_resize = setTimeout(function() {
                    jQuery('#services-example-1').empty();
                    jQuery('#services-example-1').html(initialContent);
                    FnUpdateCarousel();
                }, 200);
            });                                         

            function FnUpdateCarousel() {
                    var widthof = 
                    Math.round(parseInt(jQuery('#services-example-1').css('width'))-(45));
                    jQuery('#services-example-1').services(
                        {
                            width:widthof,
                            height:290,
                            slideAmount:6,
                            slideSpacing:30,
                            touchenabled:"on",
                            mouseWheel:"on",
                            hoverAlpha:"off",
                            slideshow:3000,
                            hovereffect:"off"
                        });
                };
            </script>
```